# How to make the show / hide transaction in jquery slower?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am using one pic for mouse on state, one pic for mouse off state, so , what I am doing is when the mouse is over the pic, it hide, than show the other one, for the detail , please have a look at my site.

http://rsvp.com.hk/tmp_web/

You can see the effect when mouseover the right side phone, but the transaction time is very quick, how can I slow down? Thanks

Here is my code

```
$(".phone.off").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".phone.on").show();
    });

    $(".phone.on").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $(".phone.off").show();
    });
```

phone.on is the image of mouseover, and phone.off is on leave, the animation right now is correct but it go too fast, what I would like is slow it down. That 's all , thanks for helping.

Comment: You could use css3 transitions and css3 rotate instead of jquery

Comment: [RTM](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and pass a duration to the function. But yeah, `transition` would be MUCH better.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is trivially answered in the documentation.

Comment: you can use toggle() method of jquery for hide() and show()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hhmm bad idea. Try using CSS3 animations, that's what they are for. Javascript should be second choice.

Comment: would you mind provide some example? is it I just need to keep 1 phone image after using transaction? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Although @micea is answering your question, maybe you are looking for something like that, for a smoother behaviour:

```
 $(".phone.on").fadeIn(1000);
```

or

```
$(".phone.on").fadeOut(1000);
```

Where the number represents the duration of the animation.

Comment: That is correct, this will be way smoother because show and hide with a duration will change the size of the element being animated and it will look strange.

Answer (score 0):

Just add time to the `.show()` and `.hide()` like this

```
$(".phone.off").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).hide('1000');
        $(".phone.on").show('1000');
    });

    $(".phone.on").on("mouseover",function(){
        $(this).hide('1000');
        $(".phone.off").show('1000');
    });
```

Where 1000 is one second, change to whatever you like.

Comment: it ''s behavior is weird

Comment: Try using an integer rather than string. `.show(1000)`.

Comment: good call, although in my experience it doesn't change the way the animation happens. cor's answer is right because .show & .hide will also animate the height and width of the element.